# Close AlertDialog when window padding area clicked

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to close a dialog on click outside, but when I click on the area of the left or right side of dialog it doesn't get closed. I researched it a bit, and figured out that it's the padding of `DecorView` that creates that transparent space on sides, but I haven't found any way to make it clickable

[image: This area]

Comment: `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true); or  dialog.setCancelable(true);`

Comment: Solved this yet?

Answer (score 1):

> Close AlertDialog when window padding area clicked

Sorry, you can't do this. Its not possible AFAIK. You should try with [**`setCanceledOnTouchOutside`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog#setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean))

> Sets whether this dialog is canceled when touched outside the window's
>   bounds. If setting to true, the dialog is set to be cancelable if not
>   already set.

```
dialogOBJ.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you try cancel on outside touch function like this

```
 dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line to your dialog:

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

And now the dialog will get closed when the user will click the screen.

Comment: Thanks, but it would work only for clicks outside of the dialog view area, and this area is inside

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
alertDialog.setOnTouchListener{
    alertDialog.dismiss()
}
```